# How to make the highcharts generated chart be scalable or responsive

Tags: charts, highcharts, width

I want to make the chart generated by highcharts as scalable and responsive when we reduce the size of the window please suggest me how to get it as 100% width and responsive.

Comment: Their demo seems fine?  http://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: Thanks for your response please check this link and select the checkboxes and click on plot you will get the chart but it is not responsive.[link]http://stockfractions.com/?regTitle=novalue&check%5B%5D=76&checkbox%5B%5D=Stock+Price&checkbox%5B%5D=%CE%94+Stock+Price&checkbox%5B%5D=Market+Capitalization&companyid=76&checkkk=FY&from=09%2F02%2F2010&to=09%2F01%2F2012&submit=Generate+Data&selectpar=+&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstockfractions.com%2F[/link]

Comment: I've noticed some errors in my console.  I think one of these is caused by your call to `$.noConflict();` before you include any other script references.  The first thing to do is to fix all console errors, then lets go from there.  The above appears to be a call to jQuery (?). So you would need to reference jquery before this `<script>` element is declared

Comment: On your page, you set minimal width of div containing chart to 140% <div id="container123" style="min-width: 140%; height: 400px; margin: 0px auto; display: none;"></div>. Does changing this help?

Comment: I had placed the $.noConflict(); after the jquery references called bu t still no result.

Comment: I had removed the style  style="min-width: 140%; height: 400px; margin: 0px auto; also but no result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form has fixed width:

```
<form name="table_form" method="get" action="http://stockfractions.com/" style="width: 876px;" onsubmit="return validation_fields()">
```

Now if one of parents have fixed width, then all children will have the same if not specified. Now, when Highcharts creates chart, then they find out that width and that's what is set.

Simply remove `style="width: 876px;"` and will work.